# switchMap after catchError does not emit values

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm using Angular and RxJS.

I intend to add an item to a collection (1st Observable), and then get the collection (2nd Observable), everything on the same stream of data.

Then I offer the Observable to the component and a child component receives it with an async pipeline.

The problem appears when first addItem AJAX call fails. I tried to keep returning the whole updated list of collection items, so child component has fresh data, but last step is never done and child item never receives the collection after an addItem fail.

This is my code:

```js
public addItem(item) {

  this.itemCollection$ = this.itemService.addItem(item).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          this.logger.error('Couldnt add Item to Collection');
          return of();
        }),
        switchMap(() => 
  this.itemsService.getItemsByItemId(this.itemId)));

}
```

Console result:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/XXXX/XXX/XXXXX/items 400 (Bad Request)
ngx-logger.js:245 2019-05-29T17:25:39.557Z ERROR [items-page-module.9c3988b4c0f0dbc7bc65.hot-update.js:319] Couldnt add Item to Collection
```

So error is logged on console, but child component never gets the new list of items.

What should I do so itemCollection$ observable emits an item's collection, despite of the error?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not positive, but I was listening to Ben Lesh on the RealTalk JavaScript Podcast over the weekend and I think that he said once an error occurs in an Observable, it ends. So I don't think, as you have it written above, that there's anything to be done that way. Maybe [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) will have some more info for you.

Comment: Try `of([])`, sending an empty array. Also, just to make sure, does your `getItemsByItemId` method return an Observable?

Comment: @pjlamb12 it is true that if an Observable errors out, it ends, but that is what the catchError strategy is for. It allows you to not break the Observable stream by having a different Observable be emitted in case of an error.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, as long as your service method returns an Observable, you could logically return it in your `catchError` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `of()` it creates an observable that *emits* nothing but immediately completes, because it was given no arguments. The problem is that the `switchMap()` operator will only trigger in response to an emitted value.

Therefore, the following effectively *silences* all errors in an observable.

```ts
    throwError('ouch').pipe(
        catchError(() => of())
    ).subscribe(()=> {
         console.log('I am never printed');
    }, ()=> {
         console.log('I am never printed');
    }, ()=> {
         console.log('COMPLETED!'); // this will be printed.
    });
```

In the above example, the `catchError()` transitions to an *empty* observable. Neither the subscriber callback or error callback are executed. Only the complete callback is executed.

Any operators that exist after the `catchError()` are never used because nothing is emitted.

You can *fix* this by emitting *undefined* or any other value.

```ts
public addItem(item) {
    this.itemCollection$ = this.itemService.addItem(item).pipe(
        catchError((err) => {
          this.logger.error('Couldnt add Item to Collection');
          return of(undefined);
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.itemsService.getItemsByItemId(this.itemId)));
}
```

Comment: Can the OP not also simply return `this.itemsService.getItemsByItemId(this.itemId)` in the `catchError` function?

Comment: @WillAlexander he wants to always return `getItemsByItemId()` even if there is any error. He states that in the question.

Comment: I assume you mean even if there isn't any error, and yeah I'd spaced on that ^^

Comment: @WillAlexander `is any error` means to continue without interference. To say `isn't any error` would be to only call `getItemsByItemId()` when there are *no* errors at all. Which isn't what he wants. ;)

Comment: If they returned `getItemsByItemId()` in the `catchError` function, they would ONLY get it if an error occurred. The only reason to have it in the `switchMap()` is for when there are _no_ errors. Is what I meant :)

Comment: @WillAlexander I don't mean to spam with comments, but he has it in `switchMap()` so that it chains when an error happens and also when no error happens.The point of the `catchError()` was to silence the error and let the observable continue as if there was no error. I just get the impression from your comments that you don't think that is the case.

Comment: No no I do fully understand it, I just misunderstood and thought that he __only__ wanted to call `getItemsByItemId()` in the case of an error. Hence why I proposed returning it in the `catchError` function. That was my screw-up ^^